# How does the reason for closing a question correspond to the actual question?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question, non-mainstream-physics

My most recent question, [Why do we assume fundamental properties like charge or mass do not consume anything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479034/why-do-we-assume-fundamental-properties-like-charge-or-mass-do-not-consume-anyth) (currently deleted while I rephrase it), was put on hold given the following reason:
"We deal with mainstream physics here. Questions about the general correctness of unpublished personal theories are off topic, although specific questions evaluating new theories in the context of established science are usually allowed. For more information, see Is non mainstream physics appropriate for this site?."

Problem is, I did not provide personal theories nor new ones. I am merely asking why current mainstream theories assume certain things. I flagged my own question to get a moderator assistance but I am unsure how this works. I have read the post about non mainstream physics but I do not see how my question falls in this category.

I don't even know if I can ask about it in meta but assistance redirects here. Please keep in mind this is the first time one of my questions is put on hold, so I am new to this. I have also edited the question to solve certain issues with definitions.

Basically, I am asking two things. 1. What can I do to save my question, as it is important to me? 2. What is the workflow with questions on hold?

Thank you.

EDIT: as suggested by Chris, I deleted the question during rewriting. I might post a new one instead of undeleting, given the bad vibes there though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93458/discussion-on-question-by-exocytosis-how-does-the-reason-for-holding-a-question).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What can I do to save my question, as it is important to me?

The question is still there - even if it gets deleted, it's soft-deleted, which means the content is still accessible to you and other users of the site with appropriate permissions. So there isn't really anything you need to do to save it, other than making sure you have a link to it, which you do because of this meta post.

> 2. What is the workflow with questions on hold?

It can go one of two ways:

- Edit the question to fix the issues that led it to be put on hold, and then the hold can get removed. Whenever a question is edited within a few days of when it first gets posted, it goes into a [review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where established site members get to vote on whether the hold should be removed.

  Note that it's fine and even encouraged to ask for help editing in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71), or here on meta (though don't overuse that).
- Or if you don't do anything, the question will likely be deleted automatically after some time. There are some questions which are simply not on topic here, and no amount of editing will fix them without changing them into entirely different questions; in that case, it's usually best to let the question go and make a new post if you do want to ask that entirely different question.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I invite people to chat about it? There is no way I could find to directly invite or contact someone. So I flagged my own question to get the help of a moderator as the reason given for its being put on hold was wrong, and that was refused. I suspect the same people who voted to put on hold answered my call.

Comment: @Exocytosis You can talk to people in chat in the [h bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), or [create a chat room](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) and invite people there.

Comment: @Chris: Actually I could not create chat rooms nor invitations until I reached a certain reputation, so I didnt know it was possible but now I see the options and I will do that, thank you.

Comment: @Exocytosis (3 comments up) If by "answered my call" you're referring to the handling of your flag: you don't know who handled the flag, and it is strongly discouraged to speculate about private information like that. Other than that, I echo what Chris said.

Comment: @David Z: Private how? I don't see why I should be "discouraged" to make correlations between a flawed reason given to justify the refusal of taking action on a flag. and the context.